# takeLeadership() method of LeaderSelectorListener not being called

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have a standalone zookeeper server running.

```
    client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkHostPorts, retryPolicy);
    client.start();

    assertThat(client.checkExists().forPath("/")).isNotNull(); // working

    listener = new LeaderSelectorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void takeLeadership(CuratorFramework client) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("This method is never called! :( ");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    };
    String path = "/somepath";
    leaderSelector = new LeaderSelector(client, path, listener);
    leaderSelector.autoRequeue();
    leaderSelector.start();
```

I am connecting to the server successfully, defining a listener and starting leader election.

Note: There is only 1 client.

But my client app is never taking leadership. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Also this is a trivial single client scenario. Shouldn't the client already be a leader

**EDIT:**
It works if I use TestingServer from curator-test library instead of starting my Zookeeper server, like below -

```
TestingServer server = new TestingServer();
client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(server.getConnectString(), retryPolicy);
...
```

Does this mean there is something wrong with my zookeeper server.
This is my zoo.cfg -

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/ex1
clientPort=2181
```

Also, the server appears to be working fine as I am able to connect to it using cli and am able to create/delete zNodes.

Comment: What version of ZooKeeper is it and what version of Curator? Do you have any log output you can share?

Comment: Zookeeper version is 3.4.12 and curator framework and recipes are 4.0.0

Comment: It happens to be a problem with zookeeper. I tried connecting to a 3.5.3-beta server running on a different machine and it worked fine.

Comment: Late but curious... what if more clients connected single zk server... still one client get to be leader..?